# Popular Item Webpart not updating for Read only users

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, document-library

I have a popular Item WebPart in which most popular documents are displayed on my site. When I log in as an administrator, I can see the documents. But, Users that have only read permission can't see the documents in that WebPart.
Is it a problem of permissions? Any ideas please!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved, I just publish the page as a major. Then the WebPart is displayed.